# group dataframe rows by index

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

I have a dataframe which looks like following:

```
index      col1     col2
       1         'A'    'B' 
       300       'A'    'B' 
       301       'A'    'B' 
       400       'A'    'B' 
       510       'A'    'B' 
       511       'C'    'D' 
       512       'E'    'F'
       1000      'Q'    'P'
       1001      'Q'    'R'
```

which was slices from another dataframe. I need to group all the rows which have consecutive indices, like 300 and 301 for example
and I need to group the values, if they are different like following:

```
index      col1     col2
   1         'A'    'B' 
   300, 3001       'A'    'B'
   400       'A'    'B' 
   510, 511, 512      ['A', 'C', 'E']    ['B', 'D', 'F']
   1000, 1001         'Q'   ['P', 'R']
```

so in case of the `300 and 301` the values are the same so I just keep them but in the case of `510, 511, 512` the values are different so I have to make a list of them and for `1000 and 1001` the values for col1 are the same so I keep them but the values for col2 are different so I make a list of them

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
#convert index to column if necessary
df = df.reset_index()

#remove duplicates with sets and if length is 1 add scalar
f = lambda x: list(set(x)) if len(set(x)) > 1 else x.iat[0]
#for index column use join with cast to strings
d = {'index': lambda x: ', '.join(x.astype(str)), 'col1':f, 'col2':f }
#create consecutive groups
g = df['index'].astype(str).str[0]
s = g.ne(g.shift()).cumsum()
#aggregtae by fisrt value of `index` column with dictionary
df = df.groupby(s).agg(d).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
           index             col1             col2
0              1              'A'              'B'
1       300, 301              'A'              'B'
2            400              'A'              'B'
3  510, 511, 512  ['C', 'A', 'E']  ['D', 'B', 'F']
4     1000, 1001              'Q'       ['R', 'P']
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael I am trying your solution but I did a modification in my question

Comment: @RodwanBakkar - What is number of columns in dataframe?

Comment: after modifying the answer I get `1      1, 1000, 1001  [Q, R, B]     [A, Q]`

Comment: The number of columns is 2, in the real case I mean